# Does every smooth manifold have a Hamiltonian triangulation?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, hamiltonian-path, triangulation

Call a triangulation of a smooth manifold Hamiltonian if its 1-skeleton has a Hamiltonian cycle. I have several questions about these that I haven't been able to find answers to. First, every smooth manifold has a triangulation. Is it true that every smooth manifold (with boundary) has a Hamiltonian triangulation?

It's also true that any two triangulations of smooth manifolds have a common refinement. Is it true that any two Hamiltonian triangulations have a common refinement which is Hamiltonian? This would be true if the refinement of a Hamiltonian triangulation is a Hamiltonian triangulation, but I'm not sure if it is. Is the barycentric subdivision of a Hamiltonian triangulation Hamiltonian?

If not, are these true in low dimension? In dimension one they are true.

Comment: You at least need your manifold to be compact, or it will not admit a finite triangulation and you can't find a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: You at least need your manifold to be compact, or it will not admit a finite triangulation and you can't find a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: In two dimensions, if the genus is two or more, then the barycentric subdivision is *never* Hamiltonian: it has too many midpoints of edges.